# Script to convert Excel worksheet to 'XML Document' file type (Save as type'XML Spreadsheet 2003')

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, powershell

I have a requirement to convert excel worksheets(.xlsx) to 'XML Document'(.xlsx) file type. Currently manually opening each worksheet and saving them as 'XML Spreadsheet 2003', I am looking for powershell script or excel-VBA macro to reduce manual efforts.

Below code convert .xlsx file to .xml

```
$Path = "C:\dev\"

$dev = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Path*" -Include "*.xls","*.xlsx"

If ($dev.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Host "Excel files found:" $dev.Count
Foreach ($File in $dev) {
          $XLXMLSpreadsheet = 46
          $Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
          $WorkBook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($File.FullName)
          $Destination = $Path + $File.BaseName + ".xml"
          $WorkBook.SaveAs($Destination, $XLXMLSpreadsheet)
          $Excel.Quit()
          }
          Stop-Process -Name EXCEL
                      }
Else {Write-Warning "Could not find any excel files. Please ensure this path is correct and 
the files exist:`n'$Path'"}
```

This code convert.xml file as 'XM File' but my requirement is to convert to 'XML Document' file type.
I tried looking for excel save as value for 'XML Spreadsheet 2003' format but no luck.
Any ideas in converting .xlsx file to .xml('XML Document') would be great help.

Comment: Isn't a `.xml` file a XML file? If the displayed name is incorrect, try changing the default application to open `.XML` files. I've had PDFs displayed as google documents before.

Comment: $WorkBook.SaveAs($Destination,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlXMLSpreadsheet)

Comment: Seems there is no difference in both commands

Comment: Seems there is no difference in both commands i.e  my post ($WorkBook.SaveAs($Destination, $XLXMLSpreadsheet)) and command suggested by f6a4 i.e (WorkBook.SaveAs($Destination,[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlXMLSpreadsheet) )...both these commands are converting .xml with 'XML File' Type but my requirement is to convert Excel worksheet to .xml with 'XML Document' Type (this will happen when we save .xlsx file 'save as' type as 'XML Spreadsheet 2003'. Any help is greatly appreciated.